# How to fill TableLayout dynamically from ArrayList using xml with inflater in Android

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I am trying to fill a TableLayout dynamically when the class is created by inflating a TableRow xml layout so as to simulate creating a "report".  I should clarify, this is in Android Studio.

My code seems to be running just fine, finds and adds the TableRow to TableLayout, but it does not show anything when i am running the app on the emulator (indicating that it did not actually add anything to the layout).  I have tried debugging and even writing logs of the variable states as it goes through the class but everything seems to be working fine, just not showing up in the app.

Here is my TableRow xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rowPatientVerWhen"
    android:layout_width="133dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:background="@drawable/my_border"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rowPatientTestName"
    android:layout_width="135dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:background="@drawable/my_border"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rowPatientResult"
    android:layout_width="126dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:background="@drawable/my_border"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>

</TableRow>
```

And here is my TableLayout xml code:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/patientTestsTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/patientResultsLabelsLayout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

</TableLayout>
```

And here is what i am using in the class to populate the TableLayout when the onCreate method is called:

```
TableLayout table =(TableLayout)PatientResultsReportActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.patientTestsTableLayout);
    fillPatientTests(DBCustomOperation.getPatientResults(PatientResultsReportActivity.this,patient),table);

    this.setTitle(patient.getName() + " Results Report");
}

private void fillPatientTests(ArrayList<Result> results, TableLayout table) {
    if(results.size() == 0) {
        TableRow row = (TableRow) LayoutInflater.from(PatientResultsReportActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.patient_test_row_layout, null);
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowPatientVerWhen)).setText("N/A");
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowPatientTestName)).setText("N/A");
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowPatientResult)).setText("N/A");
        table.addView(row);
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            TableRow row = (TableRow) LayoutInflater.from(PatientResultsReportActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.patient_test_row_layout, null);
            ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowPatientVerWhen)).setText(results.get(i).getResultWhen());
            ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowPatientTestName)).setText(results.get(i).getTestName());
            ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowPatientResult)).setText(results.get(i).getResult());
            table.addView(row);
        }
    }
    table.requestLayout();
}
```

Any ideas as to anything I might be missing?  I am not getting any error messages during build or run.